# Azure Managed Identity token version for APIM

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-api-management, azure-managed-identity

I have an Azure Api Management component that will fetch an OAUTH token and add it as a custom header when the request is forwarded to the back-end services.

For this I'm using the authentication-managed-identity policy and a system assigned managed identity. I've noticed this will create a V1 token instead of a V2 token. This is a bit annoying as I'm trying to use V2 everywhere and the claims can differ between V1 and V2.
I.e. azp is appid in V1.

Is there a way to force this to get a V2 token with the system assigned managed identity?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the v1/v2 token has anything to do with how it is acquired.
The app registration for the API should have `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2` in its manifest.
That should result in all tokens for it being v2, including ones acquired by a Managed Identity.

If you changed the value recently, remember that Managed Identity tokens are cached and last for 8 hours if I recall correctly.
So the change could take a while to take effect there.

Comment: The APIM requests a token to itself. In the BE we then verify that the aud and appid/azp is that of the APIM to know for sure the request was forwarded by the APIM. 

The problem with this is that we authenticate to an enterprise application/managed identity, which doesn't have a manifest. Maybe this is where we're doing something strange?

Comment: What do you use as a scope when requesting a token? If you are indeed targeting the managed identity with the scope, that is not really a supported scenario since like you said it does not have an app registration.